# using roboguice without extending Activity

Tags: android, roboguice

Is there a way to use roboguice without extending Activity class with RoboActivity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  It's easier with the 1.2-SNAPSHOT which isn't yet in beta.  To use 1.2, just add the following to your onCreate(), onContentChanged(), and onDestroy().  You don't need the bits about the EventManager if you're not using roboguice events:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RoboGuice.getInjector(this).injectMembersWithoutViews(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onContentChanged() {
    super.onContentChanged();
    RoboGuice.getInjector(this).injectViewMembers(this);
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    try {
        RoboGuice.destroyInjector(this);
    } finally {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

If you're using RoboGuice 1.1.x (the latest stable build), then the principle is the same but the calls are slightly different.  Take a look at the [1.1 RoboActivity source](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/source/browse/roboguice/src/main/java/roboguice/activity/RoboActivity.java?name=roboguice-1.1-branch) to see which calls you need to make.

Answer (score 0):

It works, but you must implement RoboContext and declare this

```
protected HashMap<Key<?>,Object> scopedObjects = new HashMap<>();
```